# "click and hold" with WebDriver

Tags: python, webdriver

Is it possible to "click and hold" and element with WebDriver? That is, click an element and not release the click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With WebDriver 'Actions' we can do that:

```
Actions clkAndHld = new Actions(driver);
clkAndHld.clickAndHold(WebElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where `Actions` are documented? I cannot find them [here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: You can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#A_single_action).

Answer (score 8):

Actually, for Python Webdriver API (according to tags) it's `Action Chains`
Doc is [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#action-chains)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

def click_and_hold(driver, element):
    ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(element).perform()
```

Comment: I guess you have to call ActionChains(driver).release(element).perform() to RELEASE the mouse hold.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement nameofwebelement = driver.find(By.xpath,id,name("")); 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.clickAndHold(nameofwebelement).perform();
```